# Github Copilot : Extension host terminated unexpectedly VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

Github Copilot v1.5.3295
VSCode Version : 1.61.2 Arm64
Apple M1 Chip

[image]

```
 ERR Extension host (LocalProcess) terminated unexpectedly. The following extensions were running: vscode.microsoft-authentication, mechatroner.rainbow-csv, Dart-Code.dart-code, vscode.debug-auto-launch, vscode.git, GitHub.copilot, jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist, ms-python.python, ms-vscode.cpptools, Shan.code-settings-sync, vscode.github-authentication, Dart-Code.flutter, ms-vscode.js-debug, vscode.github, ms-iot.vscode-ros, ms-python.vscode-pylance, vscode.emmet, vscode.merge-conflict, eamodio.gitlens, softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode, usernamehw.errorlens, softwaredotcom.swdc-100-days-of-code, vscode.configuration-editing, vscode.json-language-features, vscode.typescript-language-features
```

```
internal/fs/watchers.js:226    throw error;    ^Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, watch '/Users/incals/.software/flowChange.json'    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:218:26)    at Object.watch (fs.js:1525:34)    at new u (/Users/incals/.vscode/extensions/softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode-2.6.1/dist/extension.js:2:1279288)    at Function.getInstance (/Users/incals/.vscode/extensions/softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode-2.6.1/dist/extension.js:2:1279505)    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/incals/.vscode/extensions/softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode-2.6.1/dist/extension.js:2:1246531)    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {  errno: -2,  syscall: 'watch',  code: 'ENOENT',  path: '/Users/incals/.software/flowChange.json',  filename: '/Users/incals/.software/flowChange.json'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by this plugin, disabled this plugin and now working fine.

**100-days-of-code**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softwaredotcom.swdc-100-days-of-code

and **Code Time v2.6.1**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode